# Create hyperlink to some text in NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, hyperlink, nstextview

I can create a hyperlink to some url in an NSTextView using the "Link Panel". Or I can add a link manually using the NSLinkAttributeName attribute of NSAttributedString.

I don't want to make a hyperlink to some external url though, I want to be able to create a hyperlink to some text within the NSTextView. Do you know how in Pages you can set some text as a Bookmark, and then you can make a hyperlink to that bookmark? Any ideas or examples of how to go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done this in a while so take this with a grain of salt but it goes something like:

1. You need to define a protocol for you app to handle URLs. It will look something like "myApplicationName://aPath"
2. In the apps `Info.plist`file add the protocol under `CFBundleURLTypes` key.
3. Write code for the app to respond to `openURL` from NSWorkspace. This means the app will have to understand how to convert a URL style path to a specific location in one of its documents.

I think the best method for handling the URL path is to assign a UUID to each document and then a numeric scheme to the paragraph and sentences. The URL ends up looking like: `myApplicationName://UUID/paragraphNumber/sentenceNumber/wordNumber`. Alternatively you can insert hidden text to define an anchor and just search for that anchor.

Comment: That's interesting TechZen. Thanks. I can see with the UUID idea how I could make this work between documents, not just within a document. My program is a core data based program so I just need the NSTextView to display the appropriate database entry (no NSWorkspace stuff). I think ultimately the hidden anchor in the document is the best idea because the paragraphNumber/sentenceNumber/wordNumber idea would get messed up as the text of the documents change. Any ideas how to insert a hidden anchor into an NSAttributedString? I haven't looked into that yet.

Comment: Just insert a custom attribute into the NSAttributedString. You don't need to use the built-in attributes, you can define your own.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm on my way. I set up a custom url scheme. It seems that I need to register for the kAEGetURL applescript event as shown here in steps 1 thru 3 in order to receive the url in my app: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510/how-do-you-set-your-cocoa-application-as-the-default-web-browser. Now today I'll work on implementing a bookmarking scheme to setup the anchors in nsttributedstring. Then I'll write the parsing code to handle the passed url and select bookmarks as appropriate. This is pretty cool!