# Custom Protocol Handler not passing argument on OSX

Tags: java, macos, firefox, scala, google-chrome

I'm trying to hook up a custom protocol handler to my application on OSX so that I can do test://argument

In my plist I have the following:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLIconFile</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>test</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>test</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

This successfully launches the application, however my argument list is always empty. Why is this?

Under the covers it launches a Java\Scala application, the main method is:
object LoadJS {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

I can pass in arguments when using the "open" command on the command line. Tried from both Chrome and Firefox but either work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Ben

Comment: Care to upvote/accept an answer or tell us more about what kind of explanations you want?

Comment: No need to write native code for recent Java versions. For Java 9 you can use the following, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435606/access-parameters-from-custom-uri-scheme-in-java-application-on-os-x/52838951#52838951.

Answer (score 3):

The URL is not passed as argument. Rather, your app is started and then receives an AppleEvent of class `kInternetEventClass` and ID `kAEGetURL`. Maybe this post, which describes how to use your own protocol from Objective C, can help understand how it works:

[How do you set your Cocoa application as the default web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510/how-do-you-set-your-cocoa-application-as-the-default-web-browser)

In order to actually handle this event from Java/Scala, you'll need to research some more and maybe write native code… Look at [Apple's ApplicationAdapter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Reference/1.5.0/appledoc/api/com/apple/eawt/ApplicationAdapter.html) class, which allows you to handle a few basic AppleEvents like open, reopen, about, etc.; but not the URL-related events, unfortunately. On [this forum](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/Hd19l9aksuFzjLVH4g61), someone reports doing it with JNI.