# Access parameters from custom URI scheme in Java application on OS X

Tags: java, macos, url-scheme, info.plist

I've successfully added a custom URI scheme in info.plist on OS X so my Java 1.7 based application (written in Netbeans) is launched whenever the user enters "myApp:SomeParameter" in their browser:

```html
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>My App</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>myApp</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I have also successfully added the corresponding registry entry for the application if installed on a Windows machine. The problem is that on the Windows platform I can easily pass on parameters (in the above case I want "SomeParameter" from the entered uri "myApp:SomeParameter"). It is simply passed on to the application main method as regular parameters, but this is not the case on OS X. I have done some research and tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20225859/1222517) but it requires some Cocoa libraries and causes issues when compiled and run on Windows.

**EDIT**: I have tried to track down a version of AppleJavaExtensions that contains the com.apple.eawt.Application.setOpenURIHandler() but I've only found version 1.4 where it's missing. Any idea why?

Is there another way to pass parameters from a custom URI scheme to a cross platform Java application running on Mac / OS X?

**EDIT 2:** Please see accepted answer below, but as a side note: we successfully experimented with a possible workaround using AppleScript as a middle-tier. The script in [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170314201849/http://jones.kaist.edu/notebook/2012/09/creating-a-custom-url-scheme-via-applescript-and-python.html) can be simplified to receive the full URL with parameters, and then invoke your Java based application with the query string as normal command line parameters.

Comment: As a side question, does this successfully receive the initial launch link arguments? I have got this working however the data is not received for the first link just any subsequent clicks after the app has loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're on the right track.  Your `Info.plist` looks correct.  You don't need to create any custom native Cocoa code, just use `setOpenURIHandler()`.  For example:

```
public class AppleMenus implements com.apple.eawt.OpenURIHandler {

    private MyApp myApp;

    public AppleMenus(MyApp myApp) {
        this.myApp = myApp;
        final com.apple.eawt.Application app = com.apple.eawt.Application.getApplication();
        app.setOpenURIHandler(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void openURI(final com.apple.eawt.AppEvent.OpenURIEvent oue) {
        myApp.openCustomURL(oue.getURI());
    }
}
```

The only reason you would need AppleJavaExtensions is if you are trying to compile this code on a non-Apple environment, such as Windows.  Windows won't know what `OpenURIHandler` is, so you will get a compile error there.  AppleJavaExtensions just provides that necessary API **without** implementation, just for the purposes of being able to compile in these other environments.

Here, is the official latest (and probably last) version: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/AppleJavaExtensions/Introduction/Intro.html

Note that your URI handler will be called in the currently running instance of you app or will first create a new instance of your app then get called.  The `OpenURIEvent` will contain the entire URI message you send.

Comment: Well, would you look at that! AppleJavaExtensions.jar was hiding there in plain sight (I never clicked "Download sample code", as I didn't expect that to be it). I've rarely been more happy to be proven to be a complete moron. Thanks for clearing up the purpose of the jar as well, as I am compiling on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The following (for Java 9) will work cross platform (Windows and macOS has been tested):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.desktop.OpenURIEvent;
import java.awt.desktop.OpenURIHandler;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class UriLaunchedApp  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().setOpenURIHandler(new OpenURIHandler() {
                @Override
                public void openURI(OpenURIEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("We are maybe on macOS...");
                    processUri(e.getURI());
                }
            });
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            System.out.println("We are maybe on Windows...");
            processUri(new URI(args[0]));
        }
    }

    private static void processUri(URI uri) {
        System.out.println("Do something with " + uri);
    }
}
```

See too https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#setOpenURIHandler-java.awt.desktop.OpenURIHandler-.