# How to launch a native OSX app (and pass parameters) from the web?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, url

I'm trying to launch a MacOSX app from a website and pass an authentication token from the web server. I'm trying to do something like myNewURLScheme://myauthtoken (similar to the iTunes itms:// URLs) but this doesn't seem to work. (Admittedly, I'm probably doing it wrong.)

1. Is this the best way to do it? (If not what is?)
2. How is this supposed to work? I've tried looking at "Installing a Get URL Handler" in the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_handle_AEs/SAppsHandleAEs.html, but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510/how-do-you-set-your-cocoa-application-as-the-default-web-browser) for how to get an application to have its own url scheme. You'll want to follow steps 1 thru 3 of georgebrock's post. I'm not sure how you'll get a website to pass the url to the computer though. The easiest way I can think of is to have Mail.app running on the mac and set up a mail rule. The rule can be set up to run an applescript... the applescript launches the application.

Comment: I've followed all four steps mentioned in the post, but the only way that it seems to call the URL handler is if the application is already running.

Comment: My problem was trying to register the event handler from within applicationDidFinishLaunching:. It needs to be in init.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.xmldatabases.org/WK/blog/1154_Handling_URL_schemes_in_Cocoa.item

This is the only one that really worked for me! Flawless.