# Opening external application inside my application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can I invoke another installed applications within my application? Suppose I have installed AngryBirds, I have to invoke that application by tapping a button from my application. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it if the application in question has a defined protocol, in example if you want to call a number via skype you can perform an action like

```
NSString *contactName = @"user123";
NSURL *skypeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"skype://%@?call",    contactName]];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:skypeURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:skypeURL];
} else {
    // Display to the user how to install skype.
}
```

the same can happen for other programs which have a protocol definition that could be understood.

And just 4 the record, here's a list of know URL Schemes
http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

Then, if you want your app to be URL-Scheme Compatible, you can have a good start by reading this: 
http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html
and this other post is really good and detailed.

[How do you set your Cocoa application as the default web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510/how-do-you-set-your-cocoa-application-as-the-default-web-browser)

it explains how to make your app handle a custom URLScheme, which turns out to be your case.

hope it could be helpful.

k

for other case scenarios I got no idea if it is possible.

Comment: How Can I make a program such that it would be invokable by external application using call like [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:skypeURL]; as you wrote?

Comment: I've just updated the response with a link that explains how to do that. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to do that, unless the apps in question support URL Scheme, then you can launch it using URL.

Comment: What is URL Scheme? Can u please explain

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, because all iphone apps will run in a different individual process with their own runtime environment. There is only a limited IPC(Inter process communication) available, that too for system libs and resources.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to open an another app within app. However you can open an different app from your app vise versa by using

1. URL Scheema
2. Open_In functionality using `CFBundleDocumentTypes` and `UIDocumentInteractionController`.