# File associations in OS X: doesn't pass filename in args?

Tags: macos, info.plist

I am packaging an application into a .app directory for "drag install" or whatever it's called and I have a weird iessue with file association.
I set my application as a viewer for .xyz files, and the system does start my app when I double click that file; the only problem is that the path of the file I clicked is nowhere in the args[], there's only one parameter that is something like ~psn_0_901340 and I think is a timestamp because it changes every time.

So... what am I supposed to do? I've been sitting here for 2 hours straight and can't find a solution.

Comment: Aren't you making some assumptions about how the associated file is passed to the app?

Comment: Well, on all other OSes the file name is passed via command line, how does it work here?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179524/opening-a-file-by-double-clicking-it-in-objective-c), amongst others.

Comment: It's a .sh script, btw

Comment: I don't see how it can work then.

Comment: Is there a way to make a launcher or something that gets the event and then launches my app with the filename in the command line like every proper OS?

Comment: I suggest reading Apple's documentation on [Launch Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/LSCIntro.html)

Comment: "proper OS"?  Like what?

Comment: Like EVERY other OS on the planet!

Comment: I mean, I don't wanna start an OS war but come on, I'm wasting so much time on such simple things...

Comment: So what other O/Ss support you packaging a shell script as an app and having file associations work properly?

Comment: Pretty much every GNU/Linux distro, and I didn't check, but I think even Windows installer can do that

Comment: I'll give you 50 bucks if you can make that launcher :) I'm THAT frustrated

Comment: Garrus, you're not helping yourself, as your question is badly worded. "*packaging an application into a .app directory for "drag install" or whatever it's called*" - this makes no sense, particularly in the context of the rest of the question. You then comment "*It's a .sh script*", indicating you've missed necessary information from the question. I suggest taking time to think about what you're asking and  edit and re-write the question to clearly explain your problem. [Well-written questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) attract more people to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is an [AppleScript droplet](https://github.com/RichardBronosky/AppleScript-droplet).

A shortened version of the AppleScript from that link:

```
on open dropped_files
    set the_command to quoted form of POSIX path of (path to resource "script.sh")
    set file_list to ""
    repeat with file_path in dropped_files
        set file_list to file_list & " " & quoted form of POSIX path of file_path
    end repeat
    set the_command to the_command & file_list
    do shell script the_command
end open
```

Export as an application using `Script Editor`. Place `script.sh` in the `Resources` folder.

Add your file extension associations to `Info.plist`. You may need to launch or move the droplet before OS X notices the change & allows you to double-click files.

If you want to launch Terminal or capture the script output, see the [full AppleScript](https://github.com/RichardBronosky/AppleScript-droplet/blob/master/script2droplet-droplet.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/main.scpt).

Comment: This is a great and common solution.