# How to check if the OS handles certain URL protocols? (cross-browser)

Tags: javascript, macos, url, protocols

I have set my Cocoa app to be an URL handler for `com_example_myapp:` protocol (using [this great tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510/how-do-you-set-your-cocoa-application-as-the-default-web-browser)). So, the link in Safari `<a href="com_example_myapp://link">` now opens my app. Cool.

But before I give the user the link in the web browser, how can I determine whether the client's OS is capable to handle it? How to check this via JS (PHP, ...)?

I have found a lot of solutions (mostly for Mobile Safari) but cannot find anything cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, Chrome doesn't support this.  You can try using a `try/catch` but it won't return anything.  You can use your other references and put a specific call in their for Safari.

Lastly, I haven't tested it, but you can bind something to the `window` to see if it `blur`s.

```
$(window).blur(function() {
    //code to see if it blurred on a setTimeout
}
```

Then record the date of creating it and see if it's within 1 second so when they come back you can destroy the timer if it's still there.

Just ideas though...