# swift set as default web browser

Tags: macos, swift, browser

I am currently trying to make a web browser (for OS X) using swift. I have found tutorials on how to make one however I do not know how to make it as my default web browser. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Launch Services API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/LSCIntro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH201-TP1) to manually set the default handler for the http URL scheme:

```
LSSetDefaultHandlerForURLScheme("http", "com.ORGANIZATION.APPNAME")
```

Additionally, to expose the app as a default browser setting under **System Preferences > General > Set default web browser**, add a URL type in the info tab of the Xcode project. Make sure to add an Identifier and the "http" URL Scheme. Build and run:

[image]

Comment: Since I find it harder looking at Apples API use could you tell me how to make it an option in 'System Preferences'. By this I mean could you show me how to make it a setting in System Preferences -> General -> Set default web browser. And also how would I check the url that has been opened? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to add it as a default web browser however what would the code be to get the url? What i mean is if an application wants to open www.google.com how would I find that? Thanks.

Comment: @aPyDeveloper That is a separate issue that will require creating a separate question.

Comment: What is the solution for iOS. I mean, whats the solution if I want my iOS app to be detected as a browser?

Comment: Although the app became a default browser it didn't appear under System Preferences... anymore on macOS 11 (Bug Sur), but was able to solve it following the additional steps on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65479328/4691224