# Deep link into macOS app is not recognized

Tags: swift, macos, hyperlink, deep-linking

I'm trying to implement a deep link into an macOS application, but nothing seems to work.

So far, my AppDelegate.swift contains the following

```
func application(app: NSApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    print("opened by link");
    return true
}
```

I also configured the info.plist with URLSchemes beeing my bundle identifier and URLIdentifier beeing simply `zst`

In a simple html-file I use the following code to test the deep link

```
<a href="zst://test/link">Test</a>
```

My app gets opened (or becomes active when already running), but the print statement is not executed.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I've never done this particular thing myself, but parts of this answer seem like they might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/49512/7419656

Comment: @Ssswift thx buddy - that works! at least I got a "hello world" when opening the link :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @Ssswift I found a solution.
Used this code:
[How do you set your Cocoa application as the default web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510/how-do-you-set-your-cocoa-application-as-the-default-web-browser/49512#49512)

and converted it to swift with: https://objectivec2swift.com

### works with Swift 3

in `AppDelegate.swift` added these lines

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    var em = NSAppleEventManager.shared()
    em.setEventHandler(self, andSelector: #selector(self.getUrl(_:withReplyEvent:)), forEventClass: AEEventClass(kInternetEventClass), andEventID: AEEventID(kAEGetURL))
}

func getUrl(_ event: NSAppleEventDescriptor, withReplyEvent replyEvent: NSAppleEventDescriptor) {
    // Get the URL
    var urlStr: String = event.paramDescriptor(forKeyword: keyDirectObject)!.stringValue!
    print(urlStr);

}
```

Comment: I know this was 4 years ago but was wondering if you could share your `.plist`